# add scroll on slider to slide images

Tags: jquery

```js
jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

            var jssor_1_options = {
              $AutoPlay: 0,
              $DragOrientation: 2,
              $PlayOrientation: 2,
     $Loop: 0,                                      // Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
    $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
    //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
    //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
    $SlideSpacing: 5,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
    $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
    $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
    $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
  
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
              }
            };

            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

            /*responsive code begin*/
            /*you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing*/
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 1350);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            /*responsive code end*/
        };
    jssor_1_slider_init();
```

```css
 /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 08 css */
        /*
        .jssora08l                  (normal)
        .jssora08r                  (normal)
        .jssora08l:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora08r:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora08l.jssora08ldn      (mousedown)
        .jssora08r.jssora08rdn      (mousedown)
        .jssora08l.jssora08lds      (disabled)
        .jssora08r.jssora08rds      (disabled)
        */
        .jssora08l, .jssora08r {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            /* size of arrow element */
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url('http://www.jssor.com/theme/img/a08.png') no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
            opacity: .4;
            filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        }
        .jssora08l { background-position: -5px -35px; }
        .jssora08r { background-position: -65px -35px; }
        .jssora08l:hover { background-position: -5px -35px; opacity: .8; filter:alpha(opacity=80); }
        .jssora08r:hover { background-position: -65px -35px; opacity: .8; filter:alpha(opacity=80); }
        .jssora08l.jssora08ldn { background-position: -5px -35px; opacity: .3; filter:alpha(opacity=30); }
        .jssora08r.jssora08rdn { background-position: -65px -35px; opacity: .3; filter:alpha(opacity=30); }
        .jssora08l.jssora08lds { background-position: -5px -35px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }
        .jssora08r.jssora08rds { background-position: -65px -35px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
 <script src="http://www.deborn.be/NieuweSite/js/jssor.slider-22.0.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1350px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1350px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div data-p="112.50">
                <img data-u="image" src="http://www.vector-finder.com/site-images/too_big/fantasy_banner_vector.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="http://www.vector-finder.com/site-images/too_big/fantasy_banner_vector.jpg" />
            </div>
            
           
            <a data-u="any" href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">Vertical Slider</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
        
        <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora08r" style="bottom:8px;right:8px;width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid red;" data-autocenter="1"></span>
    </div>
```

my problem is when i am scrolling on images my images are not slide.i have to put scroll  effect on slider to slide images not using arrow button.
slide images only once not infite time.
and add when i am scroll slider image is slide once than after scroll remaining body content body